# How do I define a Lavaan model with the same 12 variables in two uncorrelated latent variable?

Tags: r, factor-analysis, r-lavaan

I am currently validating several instruments used in a survey. One of these instruments is the SF12v2, a general health instruments that uses 12 questions. In order to test construct validity I aim to use R and Lavaan to perform a confirmatory factor analysis. According to the creators (Ware et al. 2012) the models should look like this:

[Standard SF12v2 model according to Ware et al. (2012)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCzv0.png)

I have attempted to code this like this:

```
CFASF12.model <- ' Physical =~ SF01rev + SF02a + SF02b + SF03a + SF03b + SF04a + SF04b + SF05rev + SF06arev + SF06brev + SF06c + SF07
          Mentall =~ SF01rev + SF02a + SF02b + SF03a + SF03b + SF04a + SF04b + SF05rev + SF06arev + SF06brev + SF06c + SF07
          Physical ~~ 0*Mentall'
```

When I run this model I get two identical factors and the standard errors cannot be calculated:

```
fitSF12.1 <- cfa(CFASF12.model, data = imp.1) 
summary(fitSF12.1)

Latent Variables:
               Estimate  Std.Err  Z-value  P(>|z|)
  Physical =~                                         
    SF01rev           1.000                           
    SF02a             0.754       NA                  
    SF02b             0.692       NA                  
    SF03a             1.581       NA                  
    SF03b             1.579       NA                  
    SF04a             1.117       NA                  
    SF04b             1.053       NA                  
    SF05rev           1.180       NA                  
    SF06arev          0.706       NA                  
    SF06brev          0.962       NA                  
    SF06c             0.673       NA                  
    SF07              1.215       NA                  
  Mentall =~                                          
    SF01rev           1.000                           
    SF02a             0.754       NA                  
    SF02b             0.692       NA                  
    SF03a             1.581       NA                  
    SF03b             1.579       NA                  
    SF04a             1.117       NA                  
    SF04b             1.053       NA                  
    SF05rev           1.180       NA                  
    SF06arev          0.706       NA                  
    SF06brev          0.962       NA                  
    SF06c             0.673       NA                  
    SF07              1.215       NA
```

I think the issues lies in the model definition, but I cannot find another way on how I could define it. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Their model appears to come from an exploratory factor analysis, where every loading for every item on every factor is estimated; this is not typical for CFA, and your model is likely unidentified. At this point you have one of two options:

1. If you are confident in their model, you can fit a CFA, as you intended, but you ought to specify a more restrictive pattern of factor loadings (i.e., some times load onto one factor, and not the other). The last handful of loadings for the physical health factor, for example, seem pretty trivial, and probably don't need to be estimated. You could also test whether the correlation between the two factors really is zero (as an orthogonally rotated EFA solution assumes), or whether the factors are, in fact, correlated.

or

2. If you are less confident in their model, and want to estimate the value of every loading for every item on every factor, just like they did, you ought to run another EFA (you might consider the psych package for doing so). You could then evaluate whether the factor structure conceptually replicates in a subjective sense, but this would not be the same strength of evidence as the confirmatory factor analysis (and more select factor loading estimation) approach above.